# Is there a way to config Visual Studio with a Context Window as in Source Insight?

Tags: visual-studio, vim, source-insight

The [Context Window](http://www.sourceinsight.com/docs35/ae1147462.htm) is a Source Insight innovation that automatically provides relevant information while you are viewing and editing your source code. I've searched on the web and found a Vim plugin [SrcExpl](https://github.com/wesleyche/SrcExpl) providing the same function in Vim. So, is there a way to config Visual Studio with a `Context Window` as in Source Insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio there is a **Code Definition Window** that you can open from the main View menu.